# UICollectionView + FetchResultsController sometimes crashes when i flush CoreData entity

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, flush

I have an issue with UICollectionView that linked to CoreData Entity via FetchResultsController. I have a screen with search results, so i need to get records from API, flush Core Data Entity and add new records.

It works fine, but sometimes when i click search button too fast UICollection becomes broken and does not updates anymore. It's a fact that error occurred when i am trying to work with elements that does not exists anymore.

I've added some checks, but it not helps in 100% of situations.

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {


        blockOperations.append(BlockOperation(block: {
            if type == .insert {
                 self.ChatsCollectionView?.insertItems(at: [newIndexPath!])
            }

            if type == .delete {
                if ((indexPath?.row)! <= self.ChatsCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) && self.ChatsCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) != 0) {
                    self.ChatsCollectionView?.deleteItems(at: [indexPath!])
                }
            }

            if type == .update {
                if ((indexPath?.row)! <= self.ChatsCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) && self.ChatsCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) != 0) {
                    self.ChatsCollectionView?.reloadItems(at: [indexPath!])
                }
            }

            if type == .move {
                if let indexPath = indexPath {
                    self.ChatsCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
                }

                if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                    self.ChatsCollectionView.insertItems(at: [newIndexPath])
                }
            }

        }))
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

    ChatsCollectionView?.performBatchUpdates({

        for operation in self.blockOperations {
            operation.start()
        }

    }, completion: { (completed) in
        //self.ChatsCollectionView.reloadItems(at: self.ChatsCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!)
        // I comment this, because it cause crash 

    })
}
```

So i have no crashes now, but sometimes i get errors and Collection looks damaged (some rows are emty etc...):

I don't use reloadData() because it works async and crash when i flush data in Entity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With collectionView and tableView if you ever mess up and your datasource does match what is expected (ie you inserted a row but the number of row did not increase) the view will stop doing any updates and can appear with empty rows.

Updating from a fetchedResultsController is more difficult than the Apple documentation states.  The code that you are sharing will cause this kinds of a bug when there is a move and an insert or a move and delete at the same time.

`indexPath`  is the index BEFORE the deletes and inserts are applied;  `newIndexPath` is the index AFTER the deletes and inserts are applied.

For updates you don't care where it was BEFORE the inserts and delete - only after - so use `newIndexPath` not `indexPath`. This will fix crashes that can happen when you an update and insert (or update and delete) at the same time and the cell doesn't update as you expect.

For `move` the delegate is saying where it moved from BEFORE the inserts and where it should be inserted AFTER the inserts and deletes. This can be challenging when you have a move and insert (or move and delete). You can fix this by saving all the changes from `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` into three different arrays, insert, delete and update (you can use a custom object or dictionary - whatever works for you). When you get a `move` add an entry for it in both the insert array and in the delete array. In `controllerDidChangeContent:` sort the delete array descending and the insert array ascending.  Then apply the changes  - first delete, then insert, then update.  This will fix crashes that can happens when you have a move and insert (or move and delete) at the same time.

If you have section then also save the sections changes in arrays, and then apply the changes in order: deletes (descending), sectionDelete (descending), sectionInserts (ascending), inserts(ascending), updates (any order). Sections can't move or be updated.

Summary:

1. Have 5 arrays : sectionInserts, sectionDeletes, rowDeletes, rowInserts, and rowUpdates
2. in controllerWillChangeContent clear all the arrays
3. in controller:didChangeObject: add the indexPaths into the arrays (move is a delete and an insert)
4. in controller:didChangeSection add the section into the sectionInserts or rowDeletes array
5. in controllerDidChangeContent: process them as follows:

   - sort rowDeletes descending
   - sort sectionDelete descending
   - sort sectionInserts ascending
   - sort rowInserts ascending
6. then in one performBatchUpdates block apply the changes to the collectionView: rowDeletes, sectionDelete, sectionInserts, rowInserts and rowUpdates in that order.

Comment: So you are recommending to unlink UICollectionView updates from CoreData (NSFetchedResultController) and figure out with simple arrays?

Comment: So you should continue to update the collectionView from the delegate callbacks.  But instead of having those blockOperations, you keep 5 array: sectionDeletes,  sectionInserts, rowDeletes, rowInserts, and rowUpdates.  Clear them in controllerWillChangeContent.  Add to them in controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath and  controller:didChangeSection:.  And process them (update the view) in controllerDidChangeContent.

Comment: I made this changes. It's does not solves the problem in 100% of situations. When i tap search button very quick and cause many delete & updates of CoreData objects - no crash, but collection stops doing update

Comment: are you updating the collectionView anywhere other than the fetchedResultsController callback (even a different section that you think should be unrelated)?